# Cannot get an access to one of my user accounts

Tags: password, users

I have two administrator and one guest user accounts on my computer. I have set password to one of my administrator accounts and forgot.

Can I get back access to that account trough the second administrator account, or how can I recover my password?

Comment: `sudo passwd <username>`, then enter the new password twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `passwd` command:

```
sudo passwd username
```

you'll prompt for password enter it then you'll be prompt to enter new password for that user

```
sudo passwd test
[sudo] password for test: 
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password:
```

`man passwd`

```
DESCRIPTION
       The passwd command changes passwords for user accounts. A normal user
       may only change the password for his/her own account, while the
       superuser may change the password for any account.  passwd also changes
       the account or associated password validity period.
```